# Adding different graphics to a circle path without distortion?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to do this **without it changing the shape of the graphics**? I just used the [method suggested on this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7504/multiple-objects-spaced-evenly-around-a-circle) and it worked however it distorted some of the images. I have 5 images which are military emblems in the shape of circles and 5 stars. It distorted all the circle graphics.

Also, the graphics are already vector images if this matters. I am a rookie to Illustrator so all help is appreciated.

This is how they go using the [rotate method on this other post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/create-equally-spaced-circles-around-a-sphere-object):

[image]

The images need to be straight up and not distorted.

Comment: Hi Scott, it is just a circle path with all the images equally spaced.

Comment: See here [create equally spaced circles around a sphere object](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/create-equally-spaced-circles-around-a-sphere-object) -- You don't want to use brushes if you want to avoid distortion.

Comment: Scott, the issue with that post is that they are creating circles and not using graphics.  Would it work with vector images?

Comment: The use of circles is irrelevant. It's the **theory** need to read. Graphics, circles, triangles, doesn't really matter at all. Don't get hung up looking for a very **specific** step by step tutorial which reflects *exactly* what you are working on. Read the method, try it a couple times, then translate that knowledge to your specific needs.

Comment: Hi Scott, following the theory however since this rotates the object itself and not just its position around a path, my pattern/image rotates.  I need all them which are different to stay upright, just for their position to move along the circle path and equally spaced.  I uploaded it here for you to see.  http://test.coindisplays.com/test.html

Comment: There are 5 different images which all need to be straight up.

Comment: And what about simply using circles to determine the spacing, then replacing the circles, once they are distributed, with your graphics?

Comment: You can try this method as well: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8820/multiple-images-spread-out-inside-circle-using-illustrator/8822#8822

Comment: This might also be useful: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26800/illustrator-creating-two-colour-wheel-like-objects-out-of-23-circles-discs/26869#26869

Answer (score 2):

Two simple ways, depending on how many things you need to place.

Step one for both is [using the above linked questions to get circles in place](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20495/3327). Then it's a case of swapping the circles for your objects.

### If there's only a few of them, and/or they're already the right size:

Use the Align window (after hitting 'show options' on the flyout menu) like this:

- Bring all the circles to the front so they're all in front of the graphics you want to replace them with
- Select a circle and one of your shapes (if it has lots of parts, make sure it is grouped)
- Set the Align window "Align to" option to "Key object"
- Hit the "Align horizontal centre" and "Align vertical centre" buttons
- Delete/hide the circle, and repeat

### If there are loads of them, and/or you also need auto sizing:

Try the [Copy to multiple objects](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/) script.