# How, in Adobe Photoshop, can I create a circle of outward-facing bars?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5

I'd like to make something like this in Adobe Photoshop:

[image]

But I have no idea how to do that. Is there any tool within Adobe Photshop CS5+ that will allow for this kind of design? I know how to handle the color and glow and whatnot; it's just those bars that make this a challenge.

If not, perhaps there's a different design tool that I should try?

Comment: Illustrator will probably be easier to get the initial shape then bring it into Photoshop for all of the visual eye-candy. Here's a question that should get you started: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/create-equally-spaced-circles-around-a-sphere-object/20495#20495

Comment: Oh perfect that works! @Ryan

Comment: Okay, then I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Alternatively you could use [Rotate Me script](http://blog.kam88.com/en/rotateme-30.html). The big advantage with the illustrator feature is preview. With this PS script, you just need to guess and work out the perfect values by trial and error. I wanted to try doing that, so [here's what I did in Photoshop with the script and whole lot of other things...](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1if9iee69hxpef/Circle_thing.png?raw=1). After I had rotated the lines, I set up 3 groups with 3 different layer masks. Then I selected bunch of layers, dropped them in those folders to make them different length.

Comment: @Joonas nice, that works really well

Comment: @Ryan you kidding? They're related but not at all duplicate questions. You're misusing the system.

Comment: Jonathan, I originally didn't feel like answering, since the question is a quite broad, depending on how you interpret it... but I'm gonna try and write an answer within few...ish days. Nothing super detailed, but something that explains each key step. I think that should be good enough. Something along the lines of: `Copying/rotating the lines with the script`, `Making the lines irregular length`, `Getting the glow` ...and the rest is pretty much experimenting with colors and additional detail.

Comment: @Joonas You can also do this with polar cordinates filter. draw the lines halfway in the image and do polar conversion. You also get the right tarper with this method. Abd its much easier to do.

Comment: @joojaa I considered it, but it's actually a little harder to manage in the long run. Since the script duplicates the original layer, it's very easy to mask the lines to different lengths. Also, if you start with a smart object, you can adjust it after the rotation is done.

Comment: @joonas You can make the polar cordinates transform again just as easily. Likevise you can make it a smart object and edit. Anyway its,just an alternative thats more accurately whats in the picture tarper and all. You dont have to use it. :)

Comment: @joojaa That's not what I meant. There's no question about it being the easier method. What I meant with the Smart object was that even though Polar coordinates is easy to apply and it tapers automatically, it's not that hard to taper the lines when using the script, if you use a  smart object. Also, different length lines are slightly harder to make and edit afterwards. It's more difficult to pinpoint which layer is which line in the main doc. It's slightly harder to resize. It also produces slightly blurred/uneven edges, as it contracts and expands what is essentially a raster image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay ill offer an **alternative** to a script offered by **@Joonas**, easy or not. The benefit of this method is that you can easily just dump a real sound spectrum or any other graph into your setup.

#### Datasource

[image: waveform]

**Image 1**: A sound waveform, courtesy [of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215753/1335032). Especially useful if say a band wants their own audioforms on the cover.

Or **alternatively** to using the waveform you can generate your own data source in Photoshop. With following procedure:

1. Make a documents that's 1 pixel high and any number of pixels wide (for as many bars as you need), black.
2. Fill in monochromatic noise.
3. Stretch image to be much higher with nearest neighborhood.
4. Make a gradient form black to white from top to bottom on a new layer
5. put that layer to hard mix.

[image: Generated data]

**Image 2**: Generated data source

In any case be aware that the more you have data in width the smaller your bars will be. Shorter snippets may work better.

#### Turning the source circular

1. Make the document square and loose the background color,

   1. delete the underside of the waveform if it has any (or you can keep it for another effect)
2. Make the document much bigger like 10 times the size for example, this so you can do gaps between the samples if you wish such things. Use **nearest sampling**.
3. turn the layer into a smart object. (so you can rotate shift or edit the result for example)
4. make the document square in size.
5. (optional) Mask your peaks with a alternating black and white mask

[image: what you should have now]

**Image 3**: What you should have now. the lower the bars are located the bigger your sphere is going to be the higher the bars the higher they will be.

Now run:

6. **Filter → Distort → Polar coordinates...**

   - Rectangular to polar

[image: final]

**Image 4**: Thats it... Just add glows and stuff. Make any variations.

You may want to do this at slight over resolution for best results.

[image: variation]

**Image 5:** Variation of a theme. By adjusting a mask you can make it look like a gradient scope. Use curves to limit levels for example. Lots of possibilities for generated art.

**PS:** it took me longer to write these docs than to test the procedure 7 times. You can anlso save the procedure as a action and do thsi over and over again till your satisfied with the result. Or paint in modifications.