# Creating a clock using the rotation tool (with rounded rectangles)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have managed to create a circle with 12 boxes inside which worked fine. I came to create another but with rounded corners and they don't line up. How would I fix this? I used the rotation tool and put 30 for angle and then duplicated it around. I somehow I need to account for the rounded corners.
**360 / 12 = 30**
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I just want it to all align up. See the ruler on the image how it doesn't align properly?

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8820/multiple-images-spread-out-inside-circle-using-illustrator and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/create-equally-spaced-circles-around-a-sphere-object

Comment: I have already created it using the rotation tool. The problem is that because the rectangles have rounded corners/edges. It doesn't line up properly and I am looking for a fix.

Comment: Chances are it's faster to recreate using the effects than it is to try and fix anything you already have.

Comment: Okay, Scott. I will try your method. https://i.stack.imgur.com/grqla.jpg

Comment: I have fixed it now. The problem occurs when I use snap to grid option. Thanks anyway Scott!

Answer (score 2):

Uh I'm not sure what you're asking but a way to make a shape repeat is this:

1. Draw a line, 0 px by 0 px, make it only have a stroke with a rounded cap.

   - Optional: center this dot in the artboard.
2. Draw the shape you want to repeat. In your case, a rectangle. Place it above the dot.
3. Group the two shapes
4. Apply a *Transform* style to the group (not the individual objects)

   - Set the anchor point to the bottom
   - Set the rotation angle to 360 divided by the number of shapes you want. In your case 360/12=30. Illustrator accepts simple math.
5. Profit??? Now you can edit the things in the group, add more stuff!

### Screenshot - How to repeat a shape radially

[image: Illustrator screenshot - how to repeat a shape radially]

### Bonus:

1. Add text
2. Expand appearance!
3. Edit text
4. Add a circle, then the hands (easiest way to do that is to add a cut into the circle and just copy the inner bits.)
5. Jazz hands, add arrows!
   [image]